# Getting error "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract" after switching to VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After I switched from Visual Studio 2010 to 2012 I suddenly receive the following error (lots of them):
 "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract"

The code worked fine in 2010 and also looks correct to me:

Example of one such property:

```
public string HttpMethod { get; set; }
```

.Net Framework of the project is set to 4.0

Another interesting thing is that I have several projects in this solution, but only one project is showing those errors, although I use Auto-Implemented properties in all of them.

Comment: Does it make any difference for that error if you change the name of the property? (Say, change it to `_temp_test_Http_Method_` and see if that error persists. Obviously, you'll get *other* compilation errors if you are using that property anywhere.)

Comment: Error persists. I don't get any other compilation errors. Only 91 errors which all say "must declare a body..."

Comment: Have you checked the properties of each project involved to determine the framework version has been explicitly specified as a version higher than 2.0, specifically for that project? I take it as so, but, sanity check.

Comment: All projects are set to 4.0. It still works in Visual Studio 2010, I just can't open it in 2012.

Comment: Tried deleting the .SUO files and the /bin and /obj folders (while the solution is closed) and trying it again?

Comment: Post the full error with the related code. I don't think this is about a property.

Comment: Agree with @HenkHolterman. A minimal (non-)working example would be nice. Start a new empty project in a blank solution, copy one non-working property into it, try to build, and post the resulting code and exact compiler output.

Comment: I can't create a minimal non-working example project, it only occurs with this one project. I don't get any other error details which I could post it's just the message I already posted. Target Framework is set to 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .NET version your project is targeting. Automatic properties only came with .NET 3.0

Comment: Like I wrote in my question it's set to 4.0. I just checked it again. Even tried to set it to 3.0 -> same errors

Comment: @Preli Okay, so what types of projects are these exactly? If it's a website, have you cleaned the build and cleared ASP.NET temp files, and in any other case have you tried deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders, then doing a 'clean and rebuild solution'?

Comment: Solution contains 3 class libraries and 1 windows forms project. The errors occure in one of the class libraries.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was finally able to fix this. I just removed the project, created a new project and included all the source files again and suddenly the errors were gone. I assume the project file was somehow wrong/corrupted, still a very weird behaviour.

Thank you for all the support and tips.